# Tengo un operacion simple de division que no funciona. C

Tags: c

Me pasa que, al hacer una división simple para obtener un promedio, el resultado me da cero y no entiendo por que. Tengo las variables declaradas globalmente y ya uso las variables cargadas en otras partes del código pero, a la hora de calcular el promedio, me sigue dando como resultado cero.

¿Esto tendrá que ver con que son valores `int` y la variable que almacena el resultado también?

Les paso el código:

```
                      switch(menu)
                        {
                             case 1:
                                cantFacturas(contF);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                montosFacturas(fac,cVen);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                cDiaria(CajaDiaria);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                tArt(totalArt);
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                cantArticulo(Articulo,art);
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                for(i=1;i<=contF;i++)
                                    {
                                        prm=((cVen[i])/(CajaDiaria));
                                        printf("\nEl promedio para la Factura %d es %d\n",fac[i],prm);
                                    }
                                system("PAUSE");
                                break;
                            case 7:
                            case 8:
                            case 9:
                                printf("Gracias por usar Pellerano Factura System!!!!");
                                break;
                            default:
                                    printf("\nNO EXISTE ESA OPCION\n\n");
                                    system("PAUSE");
                                    break;

                        }
```

Esto me pasa en el `case 6` del `switch` y no encuntro el por qué de la cuestión. Lo peor es que la variable `CajaDiaria` para otro case del `switch` si responde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, si haces una división entre dos int el resultado será también de tipo int. O sea que se toma la parte entera del resultado, por ejemplo 1 / 2 = 0.5, la parte entera es 0. Debes cambiar a float o double para tener los decimales.

Comment: Gracias, funciono a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

En c y la familia de lenguajes derivados de este, el tipo de dato del resultado del operador de división '/' depende del tipo de dato de los operandos.

En caso de ser números enteros, el resultado es también entero, en este caso, la parte entera del cociente (si recuerdas cuando hacíamos divisiones en primaria).

Partiendo de este punto, se puede asegurar que el resultado no siempre será `0` (cero), ya que dependiendo del valor de los operadores, puede dar otro número. Pero **el resultado siempre será un número entero**.

```
int a, b, c;
a = 10;
b = 3;
c = a / b;
//c tiene un valor de 3
a = 10;
b = 11;
c = a / b;
//c tiene un valor de 0
```

Por el contrario, si alguno de los operandos es un número de coma flotante, el resultado será también de coma flotante. Dado que ocurre algo similar con la multiplicación, puedes forzar al compilador a utilizar números de coma flotante multiplicando el divisor por `1.0`, algo así:

```
int a, b;
float c;
a = 10;
b = 3;
c = (a * 1.0) / b;
//c vale aproximadamente 3.333333
```

Comment: no me funciono multiplicar al valor de caja diaria * 1.0, tuve que cambiar el tipo de variable a float del divisor y de la variable que acumulaba el resultado. Gracias por la respuesta.